# Object Existence Conditional

Tags: vba

I want to do something like the following.  I am trying to change what I set the object to based on the existence of the object in the parent.  The problem is at compile time, `ThisDisplay.TagDisplay` or `ThisDisplay.eGroup` won't exist so the part of the code that actually sets the object instance throws an error.  Is there a way around this?

```
Public Sub enable()
    Dim eTag As Tag
    ' Set up order query handshake 
    If Not VarType(ThisDisplay.tagDisplay) = 0 Then
        Set eTag = ThisDisplay.tagDisplay.item("_Eventwatcher").eGroup.item("Machine\PLC_OpticsQueryFinished")
        eTag.value = True
    ElseIf Not VarType(ThisDisplay.eGroup) = 0 Then
        Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item("Machine\PLC_OpticsQueryFinished")
        eTag.value = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: use `Dim eTag As Object` (in excel, no error in compile )